# Jetpack compose how to wait for animation ends

Tags: android, android-animation, android-jetpack-compose

I have simple animation by AnimatedVisibility (slideInVertically/SlideOut).
When i press "nextScreenButton" i make new navigate by navController.
The transition is done instantly, so no time for exit animation.
How to make waiting until animations ends

I can enter some delay for animation time, but its not good way.

Code:

```
      Scaffold() {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            //Boolean State for open animation 
            OpenChooseProfilePageAnim.value,
            
            initiallyVisible= false,
            enter = slideInVertically(
                initialOffsetY = { fullHeight -> fullHeight },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 3000,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            ),
            exit = slideOutVertically(
                targetOffsetY = { fullHeight -> fullHeight },
                animationSpec = tween(
                    durationMillis = 3000,
                    easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                )
            )
        ) {
            ConstraintLayout() {
                Card() {
                    Column() {
                        
                        //Some other Composable items
                        
                        //Composable button
                        NextScreenButton() {
                            //calling navigation here
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ty for help.

[image]

NextScreenButton code:

```
    fun navigateToMainListPage(navController: NavController) {
        //change State of visibility for "AnimatedVisibility"
        AnimationsState.OpenChooseProfilePageAnim.value = false
        //navigate to another route in NavHost
        navController.navigate(ROUTE_MAIN_LIST)
    }
```

NavHost:

```
    @Composable
    fun LoginGroupNavigation(startDestination: String) {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        NavHost(navController, startDestination = startDestination) {
            composable(LoginScreens.LoginScreen.route) {
                LoginMainPage(navController)
            }
            composable(LoginScreens.EnteringPhoneNumScreen.route,
                arguments = listOf(navArgument("title") { type = NavType.StringType },
            )) {
                val title =  it.arguments?.getString("title") ?: ""
                EnterPhoneNumberForSmsPage(
                    navController = navController,
                    title
                )
            }
    //more composable screens
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the main idea to do this:

```
   val animVisibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
    .apply { targetState = true }

//Note: Once the exit transition is finished,
//the content composable will be removed from the tree, 
//and disposed.
//Both currentState and targetState will be false for 
//visibleState.
if (!animVisibleState.targetState &&
    !animVisibleState.currentState
) {
    //navigate to another route in NavHost
    navController.navigate(ROUTE_MAIN_LIST)
    return
}


AnimatedVisibility(
    visibleState = animVisibleState,
    enter = fadeIn(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 200)
    ),
    exit = fadeOut(
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 200)
    )
) {
    NextButton() {
        //start exit animation
        animVisibleState.targetState = false
    }

}
```

Comment: The syntax has changed: `val animVisibleState = remember {  MutableTransitionState(false).apply {  targetState = true  }  }`

Answer (score 4):

to answer your question: "how to wait for animation ends".

just check if the transition.targetState is the same as transition.currentState.
if it is the same, then the animation have ended.

```
AnimatedVisibility( 
        initiallyVisible= ...,
        enter = ...,
        exit = ...
    ) {
          ...<your layout>

         //to detect if your animation have completed just check the following
        if (this.transition.currentState == this.transition.targetState){
             //Animation is completed when current state is the same as target state.
             //you can call whatever you like here -> e.g. start music, show toasts, enable buttons, etc
            
             callback.invoke() //we invoke a callback as an example.

         }

          
    }
```

this will also work for other animations like AnimatedContent, etc

Comment: This didn't work for me to detect when the animation has finished transitioning from visible to !visible. currentState always stayed at Visible and targetState was PostExit. I tested transition.isRunning instead, and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Crossfade was introduced as the default transition for navigation in Navigation 2.4.0-alpha05. With the latest release of Navigation 2.4.0-alpha06, you can add custom transitions via [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/)

Answer (score 2):

```
val animVisibleState = remember { MutableTransitionState(false) }
val nextButtonPressState = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

LaunchedEffect(key1 = true) {
    animVisibleState.targetState = true
}

if ( !animVisibleState.targetState &&
    !animVisibleState.currentState &&
    nextButtonPressState.value
) {
    navController.navigate(ROUTE_MAIN_LIST)
}

AnimatedVisibility(
    visibleState = animVisibleState,
    enter = fadeIn(),
    exit = fadeOut()
) {
    NextButton() {
        nextButtonPressState.value = true
    }
}
```

.apply {animVisibleState.target = true} at the declaration of the variable will apply this on every recompositions so LaunchedEffect can be a solution, there also much better way to handle the nextButtonPressionState